# socket.io creating 502 Bad Gateway on connect / websocket invalid

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to get a simple socket.io server running:

Client:

```
<script src="http://www.my-server.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
var socket = io.connect("http://www.my-server.com:8080/");
```

The socket script is being served correctly.
When the client connects, a

> NetworkError: 502 Bad Gateway :
>   http://www.my-server.com:8080/socket.io/1/websocket/20667461671864648294

occurs and the server prints:

> warn  - websocket connection invalid

I can't really find my problem. if it's a serverside/node problem, the socket.io.js script shouldn't be available, right?

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

I am using a CDN between user and server. After disabling boost/cache for my socket domain, the errors were gone and the socket became valid.

Should have thought of this earlier!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your solution? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @JVE999 If I recall correctly, I had cloudflare between the socket and the client